# Fitting order in bnf converter

Tags: bnf, bnfc

I have problem with rules priority in bnf converter. Here I copy some rules

```
CParams. CallParams ::= [CallParam] ;
separator CallParam "," ;
VarCParam. CallParam ::= Ident ;
ExpCParam. CallParam ::= Exp ;
BExpCParam. CallParam ::= BExp ;
[...]
EVar. Exp3 ::= Ident ;
[...]
BVar. BExp2 ::= Ident ;
```

I write an example program:

```
void p(int a) {
    a = a+7;
    print a;
}
main() {
    int i;
    p(i);
}
```

As a result I expect that p(i) will be translated to CParams [VarCParam (Ident "i")], but it is converted to CParams [BExpCParam (BVar (Ident "i"))].

Could you tell how to change the rules in order to fix this bug

Answer (score 1):

There is a conflict in your grammar: both trees are possible. `happy` just choose one way but probably printed something like this during compilation:

```
reduce/reduce conflicts: 2
```

To fix it you have to remove one of those rules:

```
VarCParam. CallParam ::= Ident ;
BExpCParam. CallParam ::= BExp ;
BVar. BExp2 ::= Ident ;
```